# Генерация пароля на python

Tags: python, алгоритм, дата, безопасность, password

Имеется алгоритм, который способен на каждый день генерировать новый пароль (пример пароля на 17.06: 664q1D20h9gt). Пароль необходим для доступа к программе, которая будет использоваться на компе, не имеющем выход в интернет. Получается, что я генерирую пароль, передаю его другому сотруднику, а он на протяжении дня может спокойно пользоваться программой.

В основе данного алгоритма лежит модуль datetime, который позволяет получать системную дату и время. Сначала происходит получение даты на момент запуска алгоритма, а потом эти данные используются в процессе генерации и привносят необходимый мне рандом, сами данные выглядят следующим образом:

```
date_list = str(datetime.date.today()).split("-")
year = int(date_list[0])
month = int(date_list[1])
day = int(date_list[2])
```

Проблема состоит в том, что если установить системную дату вручную и не менять ее, то можно постоянно пользоваться одним паролем. Обойти такой недостаток можно путем включения автоматического определения времени в системе, но как это сделать с помощью кода?

Также можно ли аналогичным путем установить время в биосе?
Или может есть другие подходы к генерации пароля в моих условиях?

Comment: Можно лазить за временем в интернет, но опять же это тоже можно перехватить и подменить при желании.

Comment: Следующий трюк: ваша программа при авторизации запоминает время авторизации. Во время работы  с некоторым интервалом программа считывает текущее системное время. Как только новое полученное время становиться меньше запомненного, текущая дата помечается как не рабочая и больше никогда авторизация на эту дату не бывает успешной.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Скорее на эту дату и все предыдущие?

Comment: @Mikhailo, оба варианта равносильны если пароль действует только конкретные сутки. Идея в том что программа "следит за часами" и отказывается работать если часы переставлены назад. В пределах суток или нет - мало влияет на результат.

Comment: Таким образом, надо организовать дополнительное логгирование и проверку данных при запуске, правильно?

Comment: Да, вам придётся хранить где-то "последнее" время, причём так чтобы пользователь не мог его легко стереть или изменить.